# prevent unwanted release of mouse click with autohotkey

Tags: click, mouse, autohotkey

Hi i have a problem with my mouse, when i want to drag stuff or highlight text, i hold my left click down but my mouse sometimes releases the click briefly and then reclick so that i lose the stuff i was dragging.
So i would like to make an autohotkey script that would stop it.

the way i see it, it would do something like:
when the clic is pressed the script forces the clic down for like 100 ms and then releases it, but if i hold the clic down it would refresh the timer indefinitely so that if my mouse release the clic for less than 100 ms it would still holding it down.

I don't know if this is possible so any help would be great.
thanks for your time.

Comment: The dreaded Double Click Syndrome. I have it too with my logitech wireless mouse. The instant double-click is very annoying and makes dragging anything impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help.

```
~LButton::
Loop
{
    Sleep, 100
    if (!GetKeyState("LButton", "P"))
    {
        SendInput, {LButton Up}
        return
    }
}

$Lbutton Up::
return
```